# duda con contrabarra despues de un or

Tags: linux, imagen, condiciones, script

Tengo una duda con la siguiente linea de código del script `pnmindex`

```
if [ $width -gt $size ] || \ [ $height -gt $size ]; then
```

¿Qué significa la contra barra seguida del or?

Answer (score 0):

La contrabarra, barra invertida, barra inversa, diagonal invertida, anti slash o back slash () escapa cualquier carácter que le siga, haciendo que sea interpretado literalmente. Hace que los caracteres especiales dejen de serlo cuando tienen antes de él una anti slash (). Funciona igual que los apostrofes simples, pero de a un solo carácter a la vez y se puede emplear cuantas veces se necesite.
ejemplo.
Cuando el nombre de una carpeta tiene en su nombre uno más espacios en blanco. Ejemplo.- una carpeta que se llame son travesuras mias y este en el escritorio.

Crear la carpeta:

```
mkdir Desktop/son\ travesuras\ mias
```

Answer (score 0):

muchísimas gracias, no me había percatado que era para escapar, en este caso el código se partía luego de la contra-barra seguía abajo el código, eso me descoloco y no había comprendido que era para escapar y señalar que el código continuaba en la linea de abajo. gracias :D